# Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern? Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to ELK and recently installed ELK on Windows Server 2008 and on Windows 7 machine.

But on both the places if I open Kibana then will get a message below ***"Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?"***

My logstash confiuration file looks like

```
input { 
 file {
 type => "AppLog"
    path => "D:/LogFiles"
    }
   }
 filter {
     mutate {
      add_field => [ "hostip", "%{host}" ]
               }
    dns {
       reverse => [ "host" ]
       action => replace
       }
        }

    output {
         elasticsearch {
           host => "localhost"
           protocol => "http"
           codec => rubydebug
             }
         }
```

This URL returns ***"{"error":"IndexMissingException[[logstash-] missing]","status":404}"***

http://localhost:5601/elasticsearch/logstash-/_mapping/field/*?ignore_unavailable=false&allow_no_indices=false&include_defaults=true

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks & regards, 
Narulcde.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Kibana is trying to query an index named `logstash-` and it doesn't exist, you can go to Kibana's settings and remove that index and add a new one with a wildcard `logstash-*`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the pattern is going with wildcard only `logstash-*`. Moreover I cannot see any inidcies in the folder **data\elasticsearch\nodes\0\indices**. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Do you have any indices set up in your ES instance? to check, visit this page http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty (replace localhost with your ES instance host)

Comment: Above URL returns below result **"yellow open .kibana 1 1 1 0 2.5kb 2.5kb"** 

I placed in the input folder some application logs but logstash doesn't reading it.

Comment: So the error you're seeing on Kibana is due to the fact that you're trying to query a non-existent index. Something is wrong with your logstash settings - It's not pushing any data to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But how shall I check the error? Is it somewhere in the log file written? Where can I find log files? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Logstash errors are usually written to `/var/log/logstash/logstash.log`, however, sometimes Logstash will not show any errors even though something is wrong, so you could edit the `/etc/init.d/logstash` file and add `-vvv`  to the exec command which will set a very high level of verbosity for the logs.

Comment: I tried to find out the path that you have mentioned but I am afraid, I couldn't find any such folders. I am running it on Windows and have under logstash folder bin, lib and vendor. Could you please help me further?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression you're running on Linux, I'm not familiar with dir locations on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it means that you aren't receiving any logs. Did you setup any forwarders? If you did, then check the logs on the servers where you installed the forwarder. Logstash will show this error if that's the problem.

For me, when I had this error, I was using the IP for the certificate when the cert was created with the DNS name. I changed the configuration for the forwarder to point to the DNS name and then restarted the forwarder and it then worked.

```
"servers": [ "10.37.37.227:5000" ],
```

TO

```
"servers": [ "logstash.mynetwork.local:5000" ],
```

Of course, you'll want to use your DNS name, not mine :)

On another server I was setting up, I forgot to move the cert to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/`.

You can tail the log on the client where you're installing (or have installed) the forwarder:

```
tail -f /var/log/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.err
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Just giving an example of something you did that may or may not have resolved the issue and without any reasoning for why it would solve it does not help anyone.